# Silverlight custom button

Tags: silverlight, button, silverlight-4.0

I've create a style for a button:

```
<Style x:Key="TicketOnBizOptionsButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FFC0C0C0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="border"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF14548C" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="border"/>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="White" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Content"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="border" BorderThickness="1" Background="#FFF2F2F2" CornerRadius="8" BorderBrush="#FFD5D5D5">
                        <Border.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect Direction="285" ShadowDepth="2" Color="#FFDFDFDF" BlurRadius="2"/>
                        </Border.Effect>
                        <Button Content="" Margin="-1" Width="105" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="White" Background="{x:Null}" Opacity="0"/>
                    </Border>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Content" Margin="5,5,5,5" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The style works correctly and the button to. 
But i've notice some erratic behavior when i click on the button.

Sometimes only works when clicking directly above the text other times only on the border...

The border that i've added has any effect on this??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        <Style x:Key="TicketOnBizOptionsButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FFC0C0C0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="border"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" RepeatBehavior="1x" To="#FF14548C" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="border"/>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" RepeatBehavior="1x" To="White" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Content"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="border" BorderThickness="1" Background="#FFF2F2F2" CornerRadius="8" BorderBrush="#FFD5D5D5">
                            <Border.Effect>
                                <DropShadowEffect Direction="285" ShadowDepth="2" Color="#FFDFDFDF" BlurRadius="2"/>
                            </Border.Effect>
                        </Border>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="Content" Margin="5,5,5,5" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

The problem was that you were using a button in your template, so once you fired the pressed state it was causing some problems probably with the other button inside the template. I just removed the one inside de border and it worked well.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Why? How does it solve the problem? Explain *what* the problem is and *how* your code solves it.

Comment: The problem was that you were using a button in your template, so once you fired the pressed state it was causing some problems probably with the other button inside the template. I just removed the button inside de border and it worked well.

Comment: Explain it to the OP **in the answer**